# Is there a word for when rebellion of a system is actually just a part of the system?

Tags: single-word-requests

It seems to be trendy for a politician to be "rogue" as part of their brand, creating the impression that they don't play the politics game. It could be argued that this is just another strategy, and therefore a very savvy way to play the politics game.

Another example is the capitalizing of punk culture, where you can now buy pre-ripped clothes held together with safety pins. Punk culture was established to be anti-consumerism, and the point of the ripped clothes with safety pins was to avoid buying new clothes in order to rebel against consumerism.

It seems that someone much smarter than me would have already noticed this phenomenon and given it a name.

Comment: I've heard the phrase "playing outsider politics" before

Comment: You could add to your examples mass production of  Guy Fawkes' masks or  t-shirt with the face of communist icons.

Comment: *co-opted* perhaps?

Comment: Worn and ripped jeans that are sold as new, I have heard described as *distressed denim*.

Comment: I am not aware of a single word for this phenomenon, but I have always been intrigued by the name of the Institutional Revolutionary Party (PRI) in Mexico, which seems like a contradiction in terms along the lines of your question. In US politics, politicians that cultivate the image of an unorthodox and independent thinker are sometimes referred to as mavericks, even if they seem to be part of the party establishment.

Comment: Such an event can be referred to as an "insurrection".

Answer (score 2):

Some prefix possibilities though not specific to rebellion :

**Pseudo**

> That Presidential candidate is a pseudo-rogue.
>
> Good Charlotte are a  pseudo punkband.

**Manufactured**

> That Presidential candidate is a manufactured rogue.
>
> Good Charlotte are a manufactured punkband.

Also there are numerous synonyms for **Pseudo**.

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon seems related to ***counterculture***:

> A *counterculture* (also written *counter-culture*) is a subculture whose values and norms of behavior differ substantially from those of mainstream society, often in opposition to mainstream cultural mores.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterculture)</sub>

So, for example:

> Within the culture of establishment politics, there is a *counterculture* that rebels against it.

Answer (score 0):

For the "rogue" politician, the candidate **pretends to be nonconformist**.

> "nonconformist" definition: One who does not conform to, or refuses to
>   be bound by, accepted beliefs, customs, or practices of the society.

Punks are **anti-establishment**, but paradoxically the punk culture is *exploited* by the merchants of the temple.